# Is there any way to check the maximum number of concurrent tcp connections a web server supports remotely?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, systems-programming

I was wondering if I could write a C socket program to remotely check the number of TCP connections a web server can accept concurrently. A naive solution which I came up with is to keep calling `connect()` to the server port in a loop till I get a `-1` status return. I am somehow convinced that there is a better way to do it, just could not find it anywhere.

Comment: Your naive solution may fail due to client-side restrictions, e.g. the range of ephemeral ports available:(

Comment: @MartinJames how do you suggest me to proceed then?

Comment: Oh, I have no answer.  How did you become 'somehow convinced' that this is reliably possible at all?